# Prevent more than one DialogBox to appear

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Demo implements ActionListener

{
    JFrame f;

    JButton b;
 DisplayDialog dialog;
public Demo() 
{
    f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(200,200);

    b = new JButton("Click me");

    f.add(b);
    dialog = new DisplayDialog();

    b.addActionListener(this);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object o = e.getSource();

    if(o==b)
    {
        dialog.display("Hello");
        dialog.display("Hello");
        dialog.display("Hello");
        dialog.display("Hello");
        dialog.display("Hello");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Demo d = new Demo();
}

class DisplayDialog implements ActionListener
{
        JDialog dg;
        JLabel l;
        JButton b;
        Font myfont;

        public DisplayDialog()
        {
            dg = new JDialog(f,"Alert!",true);
            dg.setSize(300,150);
            l = new JLabel("Message");
            b = new JButton("OK");

            myfont = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,12);
            l.setFont(myfont);

            dg.add(l);
            dg.add(b,"South");

            dg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

            b.addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Object o = e.getSource();
            if(o==b)
            {
                dg.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        public void display(String str)
        {
            if(dg.isVisible())
                dg.setVisible(false);
            l.setText(str);
            dg.setVisible(true);

        }

}
}
```

When the button is clicked, 5 Dialog box appears. Now I want to make such a change in the DisplayDialog class so that every time display method is called,the previously opened dialogs are closed and the latest one is the only one that is visible.

I tried doing this :

```
public void display(String str)
        {
            if(dg.isVisible())
                dg.setVisible(false);
            l.setText(str);
            dg.setVisible(true);

        }
```

but it didn't do anything. 
Also,I am very surprised that multiple dialog boxes are appearing even though there is only one instance of the object. From my understanding, setVisible(true) should not do anything if the dialog is already visible.

This whole situation is very confusing to me.

Comment: I corrected this problem by using JFrame instead of JDialog but I don't understand why multiple dialog are produced in jdialog and but this does not occur in jframe.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you cannot do this in single thread (like you are preseting it in your demo) - `setVisible` will always block (wait till dialog closes) and another `display` call will not be invoked till then.

Try to run it in multi frame env (like you have stated that your app is) but change `display` to

```
public void display(String str){            
            l.setText(str);
            if(dg.isVisible()){
                dg.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```

This way dialog will not be displayed if it is already visible, but text will be changed. The condition for it to work is that is is not consecutinve calls to `display` like in demo, but from different threads. There is no other way around. `setVisible` will alwys block.